# Feeding a list of signals into wires

Tags: java

I'm given `private List<Wire> inputs` and a method `public void feed(List<Signal> inSigs)`. I have to change signals (initialy each signal is ==Signal.X) in the `List<Wire> inputs` with the `inSigs` given in the parameter of the method `feed()`. THat's all I've been having trouble with. How could I change the state of List inputs with passed `inSigs` (notice: the parameter is of type `<Signal>`)? I've done smth but constantly getting and underline error under `setSignal(x)`. I'm attached two classes (`Gate` and `Wire` below)

```
import java.util.*;

    public abstract class Gate implements Logic {

        private List<Wire> inputs;
        private Wire output;
        private String name;

        public Gate(String name, List<Wire> ins, Wire out)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.output = out;

            if(ins.size() == 0 || ins.isEmpty())
                throw new ExceptionLogicParameters(false, 1, 0);
            else 
                this.inputs = ins;
        }

        @Override
        public void feed(List<Signal> inSigs)
        {

            for(Signal x: inSigs)
                inputs.setSignal(x);
        }

        @Override
        public void feed(String name)
        {
            ((Wire) inputs).setName(name);
        }

    }

    public class Wire {

        private Signal signal;
        private String name;

        public Wire(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.signal = Signal.X;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "\""+ this.name+":"+this.signal+"\"";
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object other)
        {
            if(other instanceof Wire)
            {
                Wire leftHandside = (Wire)other;
                return this.name.equals(leftHandside.name) && this.signal == leftHandside.signal;
            }
            else 
                return false;
        }

        public Signal getSignal()
        {
            return this.signal;
        }

        public String getString()
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setSignal(Signal signal)
        {
            this.signal = signal;
        }

        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why are you creating another `inputs` again in `feed(...)`? Isnt it already initialized in the constructor of Gate? Also is the number of Signals `List<Signal>` that is passed in to `feed(...)` same as the number of inputs(Wires)?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?`((Wire) inputs).setName(name);`   `inputs` is a List of Wires not a `Wire`.

Comment: @Neo, sorry, yes it is already initialized. If the numbers do not match, I will throw ExceptionLogicParameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bunch of ambiguity in the way your code and question reads.

I'll assume that the list of signals is the same size as your private list of wires, then:

```
public void feed(List<Signal> inSigs) {
  // Needs precondition that inSigs.size() == input.size()
  for (int i = 0; i < inSigs.size(); i++) {
    inputs.get(i).setSignal(inSigs.get(i));
  }
}
```

Otherwise you need a way to map your signals to wires, (probably by index).

Comment: you know better but does List have a method length() ?? I though Lists have only size(). Isn't that so ?

Comment: I haven't java'd for a while you are correct. Edit incoming. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need something like this then:

```
    @Override
    public void feed(List<Signal> inSigs)
    {
        if(inSigs.size() != inputs.size()) {
          throw new ExceptionLogicParameters(false, 1, 0);
        }
        int i = 0;
        for (Signal x: inSigs) {
          inputs.get(i++).setSignal(x);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Neo! Sorry, I've already chosen the right answer and I do not have enough reputation yet. But I'll upvote this answer soon!

Comment: No worries. Make sure you fix your `feed(String name)` method too.